# Is it possible a property won't be updated in time for an event handler to check it?

Tags: c#, events, mvvm

I have a property in my ViewModel class

```
private bool _isMonitoring;

// etc. 

public bool IsMonitoring
{
   get { return _isMonitoring; }
   set
   {
       _isMonitoring = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("IsMonitoring");   // MVVM notify property change using PropertyChangedEventHandler. 
   }
}
```

... and a method that sets this value.

```
public void StopMonitoring()
{
   if (IsMonitoring)
   {
       IsMonitoring = false;
       Logger.Instance.LogDebug("Stopping the real time test.");
       _myController.StopRealTimeTest();
   }
}
```

...That `StopRealTimeTest()` method fires an event...

```
public void StopRealTimeTest()
{
    // Other unrelated code
    OnMeasurementEnded();
}


private void OnMeasurementEnded(RealTimeFrameTranslator updateInfo = null, bool connectionError = false)
{
     if (MeasurementEnded != null)
     {
         // Other code to set eventArgs
         MeasurementEnded(this, eventArgs);
     }
}
```

... which has a handler in the original ViewModel class.

```
private void MyController_MeasurementEnded(object sender, MyMeasurementEventArgs e) 
{
    if (IsMonitoring)
    {
        _myController.GetRealTimeTest(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
    }
}
```

Now I got a report of an exception, and according to the stack trace (which I got from a log of the exception), it occurred in the `GetRealTimeTest()` method, and looking down through the stack trace, it went through the methods listed above to get there. But I don't understand how it got to `GetRealTimeTest()` because the `IsMonitoring` property would have been set to `false` before the event is fired.

I can't reproduce this situation myself, but is it possible at all that there is some quirk with event handlers (or MVVM type properties), e.g. the event handler could complete before the property is completely updated, or that it would not regard the latest value of it for some reason or something else?

I realise there may be a number of ways to fix this, but I need to be able to explain what went wrong, hopefully with a view to reproducing it.

Comment: Is it your app using multi-threading? If so, it should be better to debug all threads to avoid concurrencies. I can't debug your code but I can just suggest to set a breakpoint where the IsMonitoring property is set to find out if some other thead changes it. For example supposing that MyController fires that event on another thread rather than then Main Thread when you are on the eventHandler in your ViewModel you are on that different thread so you need to protect your IsMonitoring property with a lock or any other locking mechanism

Comment: I have done this, and there is another thread that changes it, however from my reading of the log and knowledge of the process, that thread could not have been running at the time of the exception. I do realise that you can't debug the code so my question is more one wondering as to the possibility of these kinds of inconsistencies.

Comment: I'm not aware of this kinds of inconsistencies. What I can further suggest you is to change IsMonitoring property always on Dispatcher (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) thread rather than on a separated thread, because any property in Binding with the UI must be changed in the dispatcher thread.